# filter a modelform based on a column not in that form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I have a model for users like:

```
class user:
    name = models.CharField([...])
    mobile = models.CharField([...])
```

and for its manager I have:

```
[...]
ManagerColumn('name', 3),
ManagerColumn('last_order_date', 3, is_variable=True)
[...]

def get_last_order_date():
    [some function returning date data type]
```

now I want to filter this manager modelform based in `last_order_date` which is not in original model. how can I do that?

Comment: This question is not very clear. If `last_order_date` is not defined on the current ModelForm, where is it defined? How does the user model relate to the posted ModelForm?

Comment: I can find last_order_date in order's model. in managers, it uses this model to return a date, I want to filter manager form based on this date @NicoGriffioen